# Given a surjective map can we always form an exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, exact-sequence

Something that I was pondering, say we had a surjective map $$f:A \to B$$ can we always form an exact sequence: $$0 \to \text{Ker}(f) \to A \to B \to 0$$

Comment: Wait a minute, what do you mean by $\ker(f)$ for an arbitrary map?

Comment: This only makes sense if $f$ is not just a map (and $A,B$ are not just sets). Your tags suggest that you mean that $A,B$ are vector spaces and $f$ is a *linear* map.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I had missed the tag, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Exact sequences only make sense in particular contexts; if you're talking about, say, vector spaces and linear maps, then yes. If you're talking about maps between sets, then you already have a problem in telling what $0$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The map in the middle being the usual inclusion map.